# Как изменить кодировку запроса onQueryTextSubmit

Tags: java, android, кодировка

Как изменить текст запроса Query на кодировку CP1251?

Вот код:

mainactivity.java

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://site.com/index.php?search=" + query + "&do=search&subaction=search");
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WebSettings settings = mWebView.getSettings();
settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("windows-1251");
```

Comment: ничего не изменилось.